# Restore meteorjs source code from build app in .meteor directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I accidentally erase **CLIENT** directory of my meteor project.

Fortunately, this **project was not "running"** so I can see in .meteor/local/build/programs/web.browser/app a file name **app.js** **containing** all my **source code "compiled"** (last build).

Is there a way to **get back my CLIENT directory** **from this app.js** ?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

The [Isobuild](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/devel/tools/isobuild) build system used by the Meteor Tool is one-way only. Meteor does not provide a way to reverse the Isobuild compiler, bundler, builder, and linker steps. To restore your `client` directory, you'll have to reverse engineer the `isopack` (`app.js`) file yourself.

Comment: Thx @hwillson.
I quickly studied [isobuild](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/devel/tools/isobuild) and seems to be faster to recode my app. But it could be fun to build a reverse tool... Maybe later, when I'll get some free time ;)